# add JavaScript to w2ui panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js, w2ui

I am very new to JavaScript. I want to use w2ui panels to create a webpage for data visualization using D3.js. 
This is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>W2UI Demo: layout-2</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://rawgit.com/vitmalina/w2ui/master/dist/w2ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://rawgit.com/vitmalina/w2ui/master/dist/w2ui.min.css" />
</head>
<body>

<div id="layout" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var pstyle = 'border: 1px solid #dfdfdf; padding: 5px;';
    $('#layout').w2layout({
        name: 'layout',
        padding: 4,
        panels: [
            { type: 'top', size: 50, resizable: true, style: pstyle, content: 'top' },
            { type: 'left', size: 200, resizable: true, style: pstyle, content: 'left' },
            { type: 'main', style: pstyle, content: 'main' },
            { type: 'right', size: 200, resizable: true, style: pstyle, content: 'right' }
        ]
    });
});
  
  
     d3.select("body")
   .append("svg")
   .append("rect")
   .attr("width",50)
   .attr("height",200)
   .style("fill","blue")

     
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

My question is how to specify D3js to draw a rectangular in left pane (or any specified pane) of the w2ui panel. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should probably check out the [w2ui docs](http://w2ui.com/web/docs/1.5/layout) for layouts / panels and learn about the different methods to fill the panels (`content(), set(), load(), html(), ...`).

The below example will draw your blue box into the main panel.

It's not the best method to do what you want (check out [`onContent`](http://w2ui.com/web/docs/1.5/w2layout.onContent) for an alternative to the timeout), but it should give you an idea how to achieve your goal.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>W2UI Demo: layout-2</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://rawgit.com/vitmalina/w2ui/master/dist/w2ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://rawgit.com/vitmalina/w2ui/master/dist/w2ui.min.css" />
</head>
<body>

<div id="layout" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var pstyle = 'border: 1px solid #dfdfdf; padding: 5px;';
    $('#layout').w2layout({
        name: 'layout',
        padding: 4,
        panels: [
            { type: 'top', size: 50, resizable: true, style: pstyle, content: 'top' },
            { type: 'left', size: 200, resizable: true, style: pstyle, content: 'left' },
            { type: 'main', style: pstyle, content: '<div style="height: 100%; width: 100%" id="my_div"></div>' },
            { type: 'right', size: 200, resizable: true, style: pstyle, content: 'right' }
        ]
    });
});
  

setTimeout(function(){
  
     d3.select("#my_div")
   .append("svg")
   .append("rect")
   .attr("width",50)
   .attr("height",200)
   .style("fill","blue")
}, 100);
     
</script>

</body>
</html>
```